# How to use one view/model in MVC3 with entity data modle to handle multiple tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, dynamic, model, dynamic-data

I have database mapped into a entity framework and then I have controllers, views to display those tables(entities). I am thinking to create one generic view to display data from different table.

To display one table, I have the following:

```
public class ATaskController : Controller
{
    private MY_DATA_SQLEntities db = new MY_DATA_SQLEntities();


    //
    // GET: /ATask/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {

        return View(db.ATask.ToList());
    }
}
```

In my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<JRAM_MVC.ATask>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.position)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
 </tr>
}
```

The above is only for one table and it works perfectly. But I have many tables, I don't want to create separate controller and view for each table. What I did is as follows:

In the view part, I changed to:

```
@model IEnumerable<JRAM_MVC.ATask>

@*foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
        @{
Type t = item.GetType();
foreach (PropertyInfo k in t.GetProperties())
{
    <td>@t.GetProperty(k.Name).GetValue(item,null)</td>
}

}
```

this works. But troubles are:

```
return View(db.ATask.ToList()); // in controller
```

and

```
@model IEnumerable<JRAM_MVC.ATask>
```

How could I make them dynamic so that they could handle different tables just by having their names ? e.g., I will get the table name in a string variable, and the program would dynamically create "return view(db.entityfortablename.ToList()) and in view "@model IEnumerable ?

JRAM_MVC.ATask is an ObjectSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using strongly typed views.  This is not required.  Use a dynamically typed view and then you should be ok with the Reflection based display of the table data.  In the view

@model dynamic

you can pass the model information in

ViewBag

which allows you to add dynamic properties.  One of the properties could be your IEnumerable where T is any model.  You can then reference ViewBag.table (if that is the name of property that you set in the Controller

everything else should be self evident.

Comment: I have tried. It generated an error message like this:System.Collections.Generic.List<MY_DATA_SQLEntities.ATask>' does not contain a definition for 'First' when I tried to use Model.first(). In view, I used "dynamic myobjects = db.GetType().GetProperty(tablename).GetValue(db, null);" then return view(myobjects). In model, I used "@model dynamic"

Answer (score 1):

I got it right now.

The key is to use .aspx view page instead of Razor view engine and choose partial view.

In controller, I did the following:

```
public ActionResult ViewTable(string tablename)
{

dynamic myobjects = db.getType().getProperty(tablename).getValue(db, null);

return view(myobjects);
}
```

In view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

<table>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
<tr>
   <% Type t = item.GetType();
foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo k in t.GetProperties())
{
    %>
    <td><%:@t.GetProperty(k.Name).GetValue(item,null)%></td>
<% } %>
</tr>


<%} %>

</table>
```

I am researching if it is possible to do in Razor view.

Comment: It works in Razor engined views too. But I got a new problem. At the start of each page in browser, it shows "System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[Tablename] dynamic ". Anyone know why? I only used "@model dynamic"

Comment: solved. It is due to auto-completion"@Model dynamic" should be "@model dynamic"